# MVC 5 Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5 for ASP.NET.

I am trying to create a custom authorize attribute. Users are authenticated to my application, using OpenId and if a session variable exists. I have added the [OpenIdAuthorize] to my controllers. When I view them after sign in, I get bounced back to /openid/index in my application. The session variable exists. I added breakpoints, but they are never reached.

```
public class OpenIdAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session["FriendlyEmail"] == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["FriendlyEmail"] == null)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/openid/index");
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
[OpenIdAuthorize]
public class RuleSetController : Controller
```

Comment: Do you override `AuthorizeCore` function?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The issue persists.

Comment: Does any breakpoints on `AuthorizeCore` function getting hit?

Comment: Is the normal ```AuthorizeAttribute``` still active? It might have been added as a global filter in ```FilterConfig```?

Comment: When I add it to filter config, the code does run. As soon as the user accesses my app, it tries to redirect them. Can I add code to make authorize happen on certain pages?

Comment: I don't know if it is the only problem, but one problem I see is that you are checking for `.Session["FriendlyEmail"]` twice. You don't need to do it a second time in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` because it only executes if `AuthorizeCore` returns `false`.

Comment: Don't add your answer to the question.  Write it as an answer.  Keep the Q and the A separate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1. Do not enter anything in filter.config.
2. In the web.config, enter this code: (see authentication mode > forms https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301240/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp.net-application-by-using-c-.net)
3. Adjust the AuthorizeAttribute to only override AuthorizeCore. Override no other methods.

   ```
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   {
       if (httpContext.Session["FriendlyEmail"] == null)
           return false;
       else
           return true;
   }
   ```